# How do I use the Save Draft module for a particular content type only?

Tags: 7, nodes

I want to use the [Save Draft](https://www.drupal.org/project/save_draft) module for a particular content type. When I install this module by default, it will be applied to all the content types. Please let me know how to avoid this.

I'm using version 7.x-1.4 of the module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you have to install the 7.x-1.x-dev version to get settings per content type.

Once you install that version you can configure the settings on the node type settings form (eg. admin/structure/types/manage/article).

Comment: Thank you, It is working fine for admin but not for registered user though i have given permission to registered user for save draft module

Comment: Hi, Do you have any idea why it is not working for registered user after giving permission also.

Comment: That I'm not sure. Sounds like a bug though so check the issue queue for similar issues and if you don't find one open a new one.

Comment: The risk of using a dev version, right?